# Adding a default number of items to list box in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm working on a project for my Visual Basic class and need a nudge in the right direction. I'm not going to go into exactly what the program is supposed to do in the end because I'm not really at that point yet. The step I'm stuck on now is this.

We are supposed to have two list boxes, one for Ingredients (which I've named lstIngredients) and the second for the Recipe (lstRecipe), we are also supposed to have a text box labeled Quantity for the user to enter how many of the selected item to add to the Recipe list. For example, if the user selects "eggs" and types 3 for the quantity, "eggs" should appear 3 times in the Recipe list box. Also, if nothing is put into the quantity box, it is supposed to default to adding one of the selected item to the Recipe list box.

With the code I have written, I am able to add items to the Recipe list as long as I type something into the quantity text box, but I cannot get the program to just add one when nothing is typed into the text box. Here is the code I have so far.

```
   Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim i As Integer = lstIngredients.SelectedIndex
        If txtQuantity.text= "" Then
            lstRecipe.Items.Add(1)
        End If
        Dim intCount As Integer = 0
        While intCount < txtQuantity.Text
            lstRecipe.Items.Add(lstIngredients.Items(i))
            intCount += 1
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        lstRecipe.Items.Clear()
        txtQuantity.Clear()
    End Sub
```

Any help on this step would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure I'll probably have more questions as I get farther into the coding, but I will edit this question to include those when the time comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to convert the value in your `Quantity` text box to an integer.  For that, you can use either `Integer.Parse` or `Integer.TryParse`.  For instance:

```
Dim value As Integer = Integer.Parse(Quantity.Text)
```

Then you can use a `For` loop to add the same item that many times, for instance:

```
For x As Integer = 1 to value
    lstRecipe.Items.Add(lstIngredients.Items(i))
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am now being given an error that says "Input string was not in a correct format." on the Integer.Parse(Quantity.Text) portion of the code. Any ideas on what I should do to fix that?

Comment: Well, the best way to handle invalid values is to use `TryParse`.  The `TryParse` method does a very similar thing, but it returns a `Boolean` which indicates whether or not the value was valid.  If it returns `True`, that means that it successfully parsed the value.  If it returns `False`, that means that the string contained an invalid value.

Comment: I see. Here is the error I was given when I tried the TryParse method, "Error 1 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'TryParse' accepts this number of arguments."

Comment: It's definitely possible that I've incorporated your solution into my existing code incorrectly, here's what I have so far. 
    
Dim i As Integer = lstIngredients.SelectedIndex                     If i = -1 Then
Exit Sub
End If
lstRecipe.Items.Add(lstIngredients.Items(i))

Dim value As Integer = Integer.TryParse(lblQuantity.Text)

For x As Integer = 1 To value
lstRecipe.Items.Add(lstIngredients.Items(i))
Next
End Sub
End Class

Comment: You are not calling `TryParse` correctly.  `TryParse` returns a boolean.  It does not return the parsed value.  Instead of returning the value, it sets the value of the passed parameter (`ByRef`).  If you don't know how to call a method, you need to look it up in the [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info. I'm still really new at VB and haven't had to call methods yet, so that's really helpful.